# Retrieving newest object for persons

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

So, I have a Person model and then I have a model name Carusage. The relevant part of Carusage is this:

```
class Carusage(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

A Person can take a car and then the system creates a new Carusage instance and saves it with start as the current time. Then when the Person returns the car, the current time is saved to end.

Now, in my code I have a list of Person models and I want to retrieve the newest date in Carusage for each Person. So if a Person has just returned the car I'd want the end-field of the newest Carusage linked to that person and if the Person still has the car I'd want the start-field.

Preferrably I would like to do this in one SQL-statement as my Person-list can grow quite large (lower-bounds~10, upper-bounds~10.000). I tried something like this:

```
Carusage.objects.filter(person__in(person_list)).exclude(start__gte(time_now))
```

And was then thinking of annotating but couldn't think up how I would proceed.

So currently I am doing this:

```
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_list = []
for p in person_list:
    latest = Carusage.objects.filter(person=p).exclude(start__gte=time_now).only('start', 'end').latest('start')
    try:
        if latest.end<time_now:
            time=latest.end
        else:
            raise
    except:
        time=latest.start
    time_list.append(time)
```

Obviously my code runs way to slow (about 5 secs for 500 person list). What would be the "django-way" of running this/these queries?
Two things I'd like to achieve: Only hit the database once for the Carusage (at least not len(person_list) times) and only get the relevant time from the database (only need the newest time...).
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have two separate results that you're putting together with an Union.

1. Cars returned.  Both a start and an end time.  There are (possibly) many cars per person and you want only one of those cars.  Even in pure SQL, this is a rather complex query requiring a HAVING clause and leading to (potentially) slow performance.
2. Cars not yet returned.

Often, you'll be happier with two separate queries when you have two separate rules.

You're actually doing aggregation of CarUsage grouped by Person having a start (or end) equal to the max of the group.

```
returned = Person.objects.filter( carusage__end__isnull=True ).annotate(Max('carusage__start'))
not_returned = Person.objects.filter( carusage__end__isnull=False ).annotate(Max('carusage__end'))
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I can see the logic there and I think this works on my sqlite-test database. However when I try to use it in my production environment using SQLServer with pyodbc I get this error: "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."
Changing the db-schema is not an option, so I think I'll just go with a legacy raw sql code on this one... :)

Comment: @Sindri Guðmundsson: "I think I'll just go with a legacy raw sql code on this one".  Bad, bad policy.  Your data model contains more than what you've revealed in the question.  That means that you may have to use `aggregate` instead of `annotate` to produce just a few selected fields -- to avoid  the image, text and ntext fields.

Comment: Aggregate will only give me one date. From these two statements, replacing annotate with aggregate I'd only get two dates (one for the most recent return of a car and one for the most recent car taken that hasn't been returned). To clarify I need one datetime object per Person. Or is there something I'm not understanding right in your answer?

Comment: @Sindri Guðmundsson: "Aggregate will only give me one date."  "I need one datetime object per Person."  I don't understand your comment at all.  `aggregate` changes the result set from being Person objects to being simple tuples of the aggregate values.  If you want more data, you list it in the `aggregate` function.  Please read the Django documentation.  Please make necessary changes.  I can't write your application for you.

Answer (score 2):

By using exceptions that way, you are GUARANTEED to get slow code. Exceptions are horribly expensive and [potentially slow down your code a lot](http://paltman.com/2008/01/18/try-except-performance-in-python-a-simple-test/) (up to 5-10x slower with exceptions). Instead of raising and catching an exception, simply use else:

```
if latest.end<time_now:
   time=latest.end
else:
   time=latest.start
```

Also could you simply use Django's order_by filter? For instance to get all "Carusages" for a given person order by start value, invoke:

```
Carusage.objects.filter(person=p).order_by('-start').all()
```

Comment: I really hadn't put any thought into this try-except clause. Removed it and the code runs faster, but only slightly. The query you propose would still need to hit the database N times. Although your answer speeds up my code a little bit it still doesn't help me trying to hit the database as few times as possible. +1 for the speed upgrade though.